# Images from Media directory doesn't show up

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My diretory looks something like this:

```
project
   |_app
      |_ media
           |_ profile_pics
               |_ 1x1.jpg
      |_ templates
      |_ urls.py
      ...
```

I already specified the MEDIA settings on the `settings.py`:

```
# This part is right below the BASE_DIR
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# This part is right at the end of the file
# Media
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

On my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from pro_five import settings
from . import views

app_name = 'my_app'
urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^registration/', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
    url(r'^logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^profile/', views.profile, name='profile')
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And finally on my template:

```
<img src="media/profile_pics/1x1.jpg" alt="asdasdasd"><br>
```

I don't know why but it just doesn't show up. I followed a lot of solutions only but seems nothing to work for me. I'm relatively new to Django so please forgive my naiveness.

Any advices? Thanks a ton!

Comment: are you facing any errors?

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

I misplaced the codes that was supposed to go to the project's `urls.py` not to the app's `urls.py`.
Also it's this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

Not:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from myproject import settings
```